# PHP- cURL enabled but sill not working

Tags: php, curl, joomla, wamp

I am using joomla and using WAMP as my server and I am trying to add a twitter feed to my website but I get this error message

*"Your PHP doesn't have cURL extension enabled. Please contact your host and ask them to enable it."

I then go to my PHP extensions and enable curl and i still get the same message.  I even went into the php.ini file and edited it in there but still no change.  Any advice on this issue would be really appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Did you restart apache after installing curl?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yup put it offline when i was turning the extension on and then restarted all services and then turned it back on.

Comment: Do you have any other (local) php.ini or php functions that setting it off?    Please make a test file and put <?php phpinfo(); ?> into it and then Ctrl+F curl, see if it says enabled/disabled.

Comment: There are multiple php.ini files in WAMP, you sure you've updated them all?

Comment: I accessed two other php.ini files in the wamp folder located in the bin folder and i removed the ";" from them both but this just caused WAMP to not start so i had to put them back in.  I really am absolutely stumped to why it's not working

Comment: What did the error log say when the server did not start?

Comment: How would i make a test file? i have a extremely limited knowledge oh PHP and WAMP for that matter.  Thanks for all the replies

Comment: it says "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library. c:/wamp/bin/php5.3.13/ext/php_curl.dll - The application has failed to start because its side by side configuration si incorrect <<<<had to type that out myself couldnt copy and paste

Comment: it also displays this warning twice one after another

Answer (score 0):

WAMPServer has more than one `php.ini` file. One for the configuration to use with Apache and one to use with the configuration of PHP CLI ( Command line Interface )

**You could use the easy method :**

Use the wampmanager menus ( thats the icon that sits in the system tray ).

```
ledt click wampmanager icon -> PHP -> PHP Extensions
```

This will give you a menu containing all the extensions, make sure that php_curl has a tick mark beside it. If it does not then click that line in the menu and it will activate that extension. Give it a few seconds to process as it autonatically restarts Apache because that is necessary to activate a new extension.

**Really could not be simpler.**

Or you could edit the php.ini manually again using the wampmanager menus;

```
left click wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

This will launch notepad on the correct `php.ini` which is actually `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apachex.y.z\bin\php.ini`.

Maually remove the `;` (semi colon) beside the php_curl extension, save the file, and then restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

***Warning: this can introduce security issues that SSL is designed to protect against.***

But a really simple fix that worked for me was to call:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

before calling:

```
curl_exec():
```

in the php file.

I believe that this disables all verification of SSL certificates.

Answer by @Chris Dutrow